# My MacBook Has Run Out of Memory

Tags: macbook-pro, memory

My MacBook Air 2017 13" has run out of memory. I restarted my computer, opened ONE safari page(stackexchange.com) and got these results.

(macOS Catalina version 10.15.2)

Any recommendations?

Thanks!

[image]

Comment: Memory Pressure is Green (low). You've got 8GB and MacOS is using 4 GB. There's no swap or compressed memory. What symptoms of low memory are you seeing? What makes you think it's run out of memory?

Comment: I open Photoshop, I do not make anything just open it, I have 50 mb free memory. I think the Mac starts caching to my SSD, because I don't have enough space there too.

Comment: I got this in CleanMyMac: https://ibb.co/3FcFmZN

Comment: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/128802/imac-with-8gb-ram-memory-always-almost-full/128807#128807

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your Mac is designed to use as much RAM as it needs. "Using all the memory" is not a problem in itself, as long as Memory Pressure is green.

If you are not experiencing any problems, like slowdowns, or alerts saying "Your computer has run out of memory", then stop worrying and get on with your work. ;-)

It's worth reading the better and more detailed explanations here:

[iMac with 8GB RAM -- memory always almost full](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/128802/imac-with-8gb-ram-memory-always-almost-full/128807#128807)

If you don't have enough free space on your system storage volume, then that might cause problems.

(Oh, and stay away from CleanMyMac, too.)

Comment: hey @benwiggy, why is CMM that bad? (can I ask this in comment?)

Comment: @tama Should probably go in a new question, but I will briefly say here: routine  'maintenance', monitoring and 'cleaning' are largely unnecessary, and often do as much harm as good.

Comment: routine maintainance etc is already part of macOS https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/413274/237